# Workflow time based triggers vs process builder scheduled actions for sending time sensitive emails

Tags: workflow, process-builder, email-alert

I have a custom object 'Complaints' and need to send email reminders once in 6,12,18,24 and 48 hours from the complaint created time to users asking them to complete it based on below criteria

```
Criteria
Complaint status = 'In Progress' and Complaint reporter email is not null
```

I am evaluating workflow time based triggers vs process builder scheduled actions and seems to me both can be used for this requirement.

I dont have cc requirements when sending email and i just have to send email to the email mentioned in Complaint reporter email field.

Criteria rule can change. Initially someone may not enter reporter email but before submission its mandatory and users will be forced to enter it before submission. This can result in change in criteria post creation of record.

Is there any consideration or reason to use workflows vs process builder or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of overlapping functionality, they are functionally equal to each other. Use whichever you prefer. Workflow Rules are still currently easier to migrate because migrating Process Builder versions can be troublesome, but from a performance perspective, they work the same way. Note that salesforce.com is trying to encourage clients to move away from workflow rules, since the Process Builder is more powerful and performs better than workflow rules, but Process Builder also tends to crash in weird ways, especially in unit tests, which might be a reason to prefer Workflow Rules instead.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. we  may need to send lot of emails per day so scalability wise as well i am assuming workflow alerts can handle it well. Documentation says its 1000 per standard license?

Comment: @RedDevil Workflow Alerts and Process Builder Alerts are a shared limit; you may use any combination of either. And yes, it looks like 1k/license for production orgs.